# Is there a way to retrieve application key credentials for an Okta application using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, okta, okta-api

As part of the [documentation for enabling OAuth 2.0 for provisioning between source/target (hub/spoke) orgs](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/secure-oauth-between-orgs/main/#add-an-org2org-app-integration-in-a-spoke-org), Okta instructs users to make a `POST /api/v1/apps` request to the spoke org to gather key credentials for the Org2Org application.

I would like to automate this process using terraform, but I am not able to identify a terraform resource or data source that would provide me with the key credentials. Example output below:

```json
[
    {
        "kty": "RSA",
        "created": "2022-01-20T19:50:14.000Z",
        "lastUpdated": "2022-01-20T19:50:14.000Z",
        "expiresAt": "2024-01-20T19:50:13.000Z",
        "kid": "sf-jWwRKMUU55 ... GucHLxIh_-fYLAofB8",
        "use": "sig",
        "x5c": [
            "MIIDqDCCApCgAwIBAgIGAX55CiDiMA0GCSqG ... c5Iuo9j3wpemDSgGapXQ=="
        ],
        "x5t#S256": "v-v2V8soFmXuhC ... nrJ4ho-N3P8aASFc",
        "e": "AQAB",
        "n": "gIxwqCNkdAb1ioyNBY2boqUCrMj_NSFJAl ... 7dZFiAYF7p_k3XMXOh-hsL_D8FDQ"
    }
]
```

Ideally, I would like to use a terraform data source to gather the credential keys and use them to create an OAuth 2.0 service app, as the [Okta documentation instructs](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/secure-oauth-between-orgs/main/#create-an-oauth-2-0-service-app-in-the-hub-org).

```
data "okta_app_saml" "okta_customer_poc" {
  provider = okta.internal_us

  label = "Okta Customer PoC"
}
resource "okta_app_oauth" "example" {
  label          = "example"
  type           = "service"
  response_types = ["token"]
  grant_types    = ["client_credentials"]
  token_endpoint_auth_method = "private_key_jwt"

  jwks {
    kty = data.okta_app_saml.okta_customer_poc.credentials.jwks[0].kty
    kid = data.okta_app_saml.okta_customer_poc.credentials.jwks[0].kid
    x   = data.okta_app_saml.okta_customer_poc.credentials.jwks[0].x
    y   = data.okta_app_saml.okta_customer_poc.credentials.jwks[0].y
  }

  jwks {
    kty = data.okta_app_saml.okta_customer_poc.credentials.jwks[1].kty
    kid = data.okta_app_saml.okta_customer_poc.credentials.jwks[1].kid
    e   = data.okta_app_saml.okta_customer_poc.credentials.jwks[1].e
    n   = data.okta_app_saml.okta_customer_poc.credentials.jwks[1].n
  }

}
```

I'm gathering that the above solution isn't currently supported, but I'm wondering if I'm missing some other obvious solution.